# Two polylines to one singlepart polyline when endpoint share 3 vertices

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm trying to merge/dissolve two polylines to create a singlepart polyline. The problem is that the two lines are a straight line with a loop (circle) at the end, meaning they share 3 vertices at the end point and so dissolve does not create a singlepart line. I need a line that goes towards the loop and counterclockwise around it ending where it meets the start of the loop and so far that only way I've found that works is to redigitize it manually.

The lines are road + cul de sacs.

Is there a tool or a way to make dissolve do this properly?

Comment: Clockwise is a fairly precise requirement, I'd say there isn't any easy way to do this but it could be done in python or ArcObjects.. assuming that each section of the road has the same unique identifier (name is a good identifier) otherwise you will get some fairly bad results. Is either python or ArcObjects an option for you?

Comment: Clockwise is easy for closed line providing no self intersection. Convert to polygon, convert to line. Creating self intersected line in ArcGis - manual only, in script set of points will produce multipart line.